# Fail normality test but the qqplot is a straight line

Tags: regression, residuals, sas, qq-plot

I am using SAS 9.4 . 
My aim is to find out whether my residual is normal or not, so i type this:

`proc univariate data= residual normal;
var rstd;
qqplot rstd/ norml(mu=est sigma=est);
run;`

In my output the qqplot is clearly a straight while 4 pavlue of statistic for the normality is less then 5%.

How can i interpret this?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you show the qq-plot?

Comment: currently i don't have the computer but i can tell you the points are nearly falling on the normal line , no heavytailness

Comment: without the plot we are not going to be able to help you.

Comment: What is your sample size?  If it is large, then the p value will be low even for tiny violations of normality

Comment: my sample size is 270,and i have attached the photos

Comment: What do you mean by "4 pavlue"? Can you edit?

Comment: "In my output the qqplot is clearly a straight". That is a subjective statement. IMO it is not clearly a straight line.

Comment: so in my case,it is possibly due to the large number of n?

Comment: See also: [Is normality testing 'essentially useless'?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/2492/7290)